# ng-repeat over array containing data with inner array having key-value similar will group together?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of data containing another array of data with key(TypeOfServiceAssigned:Array(2)) common in both inner array, I want to apply ng-repeat in such a way that similar key-value will group together and differnt one group seperatly.

for better explaination see below:

```
Array = [
  {
    Quotation:1200,
    TypeOfServiceAssigned:["Primary", "Partial Services"],
    VendorEmail:"A@gmail.com"
  },{
    Quotation:1350,
    TypeOfServiceAssigned:["Partial Services"],
    VendorEmail:"Add@gmail.com"
  }
];
```

I want to apply ng repeat over Array so that it will show me two group depending upon TypeOfServiceAssigned value , one for Primary and second for Partial Sevicers. And for   Partial Sevicers, it will show me two list.

Comment: I would prepare the array in your controller or in a service, whatever applies to your case. Then just repeat over them. But, what have you tried?

Comment: kindly share fiddle for the things tried out from your end.

Answer (score 2):

Most efficient method is to handcraft function to return exact what you want..
[example here](https://jsfiddle.net/xrspq630/) , then bind it to your nested ng-repeat as you would do normally  :)

However normally we should do this on server side/service but anyway...

```
function doGroupBy() {
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
        var current = input[i].TypeOfServiceAssigned;
        for (var j = 0; j < current.length; ++j)
            if (result[current[j]])
                result[current[j]].push(input[i]); // result[current[j]] = [...result[current[j]], input[i]];
            else
                result[current[j]] = [input[i]];
    }

    return result;
}

var input = [{ Quotation: 1200, TypeOfServiceAssigned: ["Primary", "Partial Services"], VendorEmail: "A@gmail.com" },
             { Quotation: 1350, TypeOfServiceAssigned: ["Partial Services"], VendorEmail: "Add@gmail.com" }];

var testResult = doGroupBy(input);

for (var key in testResult) {
    console.log('-----------');
    console.log(key);
    console.log(testResult[key]);
}
```

Comment: spread operator is throwing errors in angularjs, (in gulp console)